# How can I log the output of an application in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, logging

I would like to log the output of an application running on Windows 7 to a file.

In Linux I just redirect the output to a log file by doing something like this:

```
./application >> /path/to/log.txt 2>&1 &
```

What would be the equivalent in Windows 7 (or a better option in case it exists)?

Comment: That would be the way to do it. Assuming the application generates any output on a console/stdout. If not it depends on the application.

Comment: Yes, it is stdout/stderr. I wasn't aware it works the same way as Linux. Should I do it in cmd.exe or in Powershell?

Comment: At the command prompt many commands will allow you to output the results to a file i.e. _ipconfig /all >c:\temp\file.txt_

Not sure how you'd get non command line apps to do that.

Comment: It shouldn't matter whenever you use cmd or PowerShell. If you're trying to do this for PowerShell scripts beware that there might be output that isn't being redirected regardless. An example would be `Write-Host` as strange as it is. For most other cases it should work from what I know.

Comment: By the way, is there a way to follow the logging as it is generated the same way I do `tail -f log.txt` in Linux? Edit: Nevermind, I found some options [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/7263/convenient-windows-equivalent-to-tail-f-logfile).